# setImage does not show the new image in JavaScript with Spotify Apps API

Tags: javascript, spotify, spotify-app

I am trying to set a different image with the [`setImage` method](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/views/1.0/image-image.html#setImage).

The issue is that the new image becomes visible just for a very short period of time, but then fades away in to the original image.

Besides that, the play button disappears.

Here is my code:

```
require(['$api/models', '$views/image#Image'], function(models, Image) {

    // Play a single track
    var track = models.Track.fromURI('spotify:track:7B1Dl3tXqySkB8OPEwVvSu');
    var image = Image.forTrack(track, {player: true});

    // A line added by me to set the new image
    image.setImage("/img/spotify-logo.png");

    // Pass the player HTML code to the #single-track-player div
    document.getElementById('single-track-player')
        .appendChild(image.node);
});
```

This code is mostly taken from the [Spotify Apps Tutorial](https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial/blob/master/tutorials/playing/play-track.html).

The only line I have added is that with the `setImage` method.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a race condition when setting the custom image using `Image.setImage`.

A solution is to use the [`Image.fromSource`](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/views/1.0/image-image.html#fromSource) method:

```
require(['$api/models', '$views/image#Image'], function(models, Image) {

    // Play a single track
    var track = models.Track.fromURI('spotify:track:7B1Dl3tXqySkB8OPEwVvSu');
    var image = Image.fromSource("/img/spotify-logo.png", {
        playerItem: track,
        player: true
    });

    // Pass the player HTML code to the #single-track-player div
    document.getElementById('single-track-player')
        .appendChild(image.node);

});
```